# OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument when trying to create a txt file

Tags: python, oserror

I am learning about relative and absolute paths in Python. I was working on a project, that is supposed to write personalized letters and save it as a .txt file, but it seems that I can't save it as `f"letter_for_{name}"`. Every time I try to, I get this Error: "OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument". Maybe, it's the fault of russian as a system language, because some folders are translated and paths don't work at all without two backslashes.

Here is a bit of code:

```
with open(".\\Input\\Letters\\starting_letter.txt", mode="r") as starting_letter:
    contents = starting_letter.read()

with open(".\\Input\\Names\\invited_names.txt", mode="r") as names:
    names_list = names.readlines()

for name in names_list:
    name_letter = name.strip()
    letter = contents.replace("[name]", name)
    a = open(f".\\Output\\ReadyToSend\\letter_for_{name}.txt", mode="w")
    a.write(letter)
    a.close()
```

Comment: first display `Current Working Directory` with  `os.gecwd()` to see if you create it in correct folder. `open()` can create file but not folders and first you may need to use `os.makedirs(...)`

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: Char \ has special meaning in string (ie. `\t` for `tab`, `\n` for new line, `\Uxxx` for unicode, etc.) - even in path - so you should always use \\ or add prefix `r` to create `raw string` - like `r".\Input\Letters\starting_letter.txt"`